# Is it true "JavaScript files are not reliably cached by browsers, CSS files are"

Tags: javascript, css, performance

as mentioned on this site

> Note that while JavaScript files are
>   not reliably cached by browsers, CSS
>   files are.

http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/http/

Comment: I would be suspicious of such a claim, since the article doesn't offer a single word of explanation or support for it. I would also be suspicious of anyone who still wraps JavaScript code in an HTML comment, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: I agree with Syntactic.  Also, please note when the article was written: "17 Dec 2003".  Even if that was corrected then (and I have no idea if it was or still is correct), it can easily be very out of date at this point.

Comment: Drop that site. Use the [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) recommendations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browsers I know of "reliably cache" all kinds of static data (including JS and CSS, as well as images, HTML, etc) as long as they're served with proper cache-support headers.  Maybe the text means something different than actual caching, such as parsing just once and then keeping some efficient internal format...?  I don't know which browsers do or don't do that for different kinds of files, but at least under this hypothesis I can see why (e.g) CSS might be easier for the browser to keep in preprocessed form than JS.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason to make that claim expressly for JavaScript files. I can, however, see an argument made that caching can be unreliable in general regardless of the file type sent, depending on the server configuration, additional headers that are sent, proxies and caches, and how the end-user's browser is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

This is good if we want to actual cache the resource. If we want to force a new download set no-cache, which forces caches to submit the request to the origin server for validation before releasing a cached copy, every time. This is useful to assure that authentication is respected (in combination with public), or to maintain rigid freshness, without sacrificing all of the benefits of caching.

[HTTP Server-Specified Expiration - specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2)

Comment: You've posted two identical answers which have been flagged, that's ok but we'd prefer it if you tailored answers for each question. However the answer is plagiarised from two different sources. First sentence from [Optimize caching - Overview](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html). Third & fourth sentences from: [Cache-Control HTTP Headers - no-cache](http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html). It would be better and fairer to provide links to the source material and format these as quotes rather than pass off as your own. Thanks.